# Web server answer only on part of all GET requests from C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, http

I send a lot of GET requests on one server using C sockets. Server answers only part of them. Wireshark said that all packets are correct and sent. If i call recv() after send() until free buffer and only after that call send() again, all works fine. If i create new socket for each send(), server answer correctly too. But i need to send all request to already connected socket without disconnecting. I already tried TCP_NODELAY, but it didnt help me.

UPD simple example about what am i trying to do:

```
int tcpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//------------------OPTIONS-------------------------
int flag = 1;
if (setsockopt(tcpSocket, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    perror("TCP_NODELAY");
int on = 1;
setsockopt(tcpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));
struct linger lin;
unsigned int y=sizeof(lin);
lin.l_onoff=1;
lin.l_linger=5;
setsockopt(tcpSocket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER,(void*)(&lin), y);
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 5;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
if (setsockopt (tcpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
                sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt failed\n");

if (setsockopt (tcpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
                sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt failed\n");
int enable_keep_alive = 1;
if (setsockopt(tcpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &enable_keep_alive, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    error("SO_KEEPALIVE");
//-------------------------------------------

connect(tcpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));

do {
  sprintf(request, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: Keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
  send(tcpSocket, request, strlen(request), 0);
} while (!finish);

shutdown(tcpSocket, 2);
close(tcpSocket);
```

**UPD**
Maybe my problem was not very clear, sorry for that, what i want to do is sending a lot of requests to one server without waiting for response or recreating socket. So i need to send a lot of requests to one server as fast as i can, but recv and recreating socket are slowing this program.

Comment: And you do set the [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) header?

Comment: Yes. Server keeps connection.

Comment: What about send request one by one? I mean you send the request and then wait the respond, the send another request ... ect

Comment: Yes, it works in such way. As i said " If i call recv() after send() until free buffer and only after that call send() again, all works fine."

Comment: So but why can i send a lot of requests when i recreate socket for every request?

Comment: Because then you send each request on a different connection, which is okay (and how most modern web-browsers work, they can create several connections to send requests in parallel to the server, even for a single page).

Comment: That's not correct. HTTP/1.1 explicitly allows pipelining of requests, i.e. sending multiple requests without waiting for a response. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696733/issuing-multiple-requests-before-getting-response#.

Comment: @Phillip Ah you are correct. I retract that comment. Saik0s, you might want to add some code to show what you are doing. It will make it much easier to help you then.

Comment: When you say "answers only part of them," do you mean that you only see replies to some requests or that you see replies to partial requests? It sounds like the former, but the "extra `recv()`" behavior seems more like the latter.

Comment: Just a guess. If you do not call `recv` the server's send buffer becomes full, server interprets the situation as a connection problem and closes the connection.

Comment: I guess the code you shown is just an example, and not the actual code? Otherwise you have an infinite loop (as you don't seem to change `finish` anywhere in the loop. You should also check for errors from `send`. *And* call `recv` sometimes as well, to know when the connection has been closed. In fact, I would have used `select` to check if the socket could be written to (and then do `send`) or read from (might indicate connection closed, as well as reading the responses).

Comment: Yes, this is just example, of course i check all errors, and finish changes when needed. And i call recv after sending. I only show how i send requests.

Comment: Maybe your recv() results in partial reads?

Comment: As i said in question "If i call recv() after send() until free buffer and only after that call send() again, all works fine." So now i call recv in loop until buffer i free. I asked how to send a lot of requests to one server without waiting for response or recreating socket.